# Angular Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, lazy-loading

been having a little trouble recently with lazy loading.
Now I'm not sure if this is supposed to be happening or not (and I've tried searching for the issue but I'm not even sure how to word it if I'm being honest).

So 
I do everything for setup of the lazy loaded module like you would usually do. Everything from making sure that the app routing module is setup correctly as so:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'home', 
    loadChildren: './shared/modules/homepage/homepage.module#HomepageModule' 
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then, making sure that everything is correctly setup with the lazy loaded module, in this case, the homepage module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//~~~~ Important:
import { HomeMainComponent } from './components/home-main/home-main.component';

const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    component: HomeMainComponent, 
  }
]


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeMainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes),
  ],
  exports: [
    HomeMainComponent 
  ]
})
export class HomepageModule { }
```

Now I have yet to do a redirect path for path: '', in the app router module, but for some reason at localhost:4200/ , it loads the home module. In Augury this is what I'm seeing currently:

[Augury Routing Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J7yK.png)

Edit* snipped code of app.module.ts:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

//~~~~ Important:
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { FeaturesModule } from './features/features.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    FeaturesModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Edit* What it looks like when I go to home route:
[image]

Edit* changed the homepage.module.ts router into it's own file to homepage-routing.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeMainComponent } from './components/home-main/home-main.component';


const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: HomeMainComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomeMainComponent,
    ],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)],
    exports: [
        HomeMainComponent,
        RouterModule]
})
export class HomepageRoutingModule { }
```

I've done everything correctly from what I understand, and I've done this tons of times to know that there's something wrong here. Anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing? Thanks!

Solved**** :
Turns out I was using app-routing.module and I should be using a routing module for Shared.module instead. So basically, get rid or app-routing.module and do everything that I did in there within the shared-routing.module and that will resolve the issue. Thanks, everyone for the help!

Comment: What Angular version are you on? The way you use lazy loaded routes changed somewhere around Angular 7/8, I don't remember the exact version.

Comment: I'm currently using 8 right now. attempted to use the new method to create a lazy loaded route and got the same issue. Brb gonna double check just in case.

Comment: I edit the answer, you should also export your RouterModule...

Comment: Do you really have a folder named `shared` in the same directory that your `AppRoutingModule` is defined in?

Comment: yeah just tried the new method for Angular 8 but still getting the same issue. The Router Tree still looks the same.

Comment: yeah is that a bad thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way of lazy loading changed in the newer versions, refactor the config of routes to:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'home', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./shared/modules/homepage/homepage.module').then(m => m.HomepageModule)
  },
];
```

And export the RouterModule in your HomeModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeMainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes),
  ],
  exports: [
    HomeMainComponent,
    RouterModule 
  ]
})
export class HomepageModule { }
```

Comment: So just tried switching it to the newer method, but still getting the same routing issue. Could it be related to the router-outlet?

Comment: Did you export the Router module as i mentioned?

Comment: Yeah just exported the router module, issue is still the same.

Comment: Try to create HomeRoutingModule isolating your lazy routes, just like AppRoutingModule

Comment: Also added a screen cap of the router tree when I go to the /home route, if that helps out at all

Comment: So, I changed all the routing to its own homepage-routing.module.ts file, but the issue still occurs. Before I even go to the /home route, the module is loaded. I'm thinking maybe somewhere I missed a step, I'm gonna round back and try rebuilding to see what happens.

Comment: Ended up figuring this out. since I'm using several modules (core, shared, features *note still trying to figure how to use angular like this*), I made the mistake of trying to lazy load the home.module from the app-routing.module... Basically from what I'm seeing in old examples that I've worked on in the past and also from different online sources, I would need to get rid of the app-routing.module and create a routing module for the shared.module and do everything there. Sorry for the headaches, and thanks for helping me out!!!